# Popup appears when trying to download a xml file

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I updated Firefox browser and Selenium library:

from:

```
Selenium: 2.53.1
Firefox browser: 46.0.1
```

to:

```
Selenium: 3.141.0
Firefox browser: 93.0
```

Unfortunately, now when I try to download a file, a Windows popup appears:
[image]

Using previous Selenium and Firefox configuration, the file was downloaded after pressing a button, without any popup. This was done by settings mime/type configuration before driver's initialization:

```cs
// setup firefox profile
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", @"d:\downloads");
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml,text/xml");

// setup firefox options
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

// setup selenium driver service
var firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService("d:\gecko");

// setup selenium driver
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, options);
```

Any ideas why it is not working right now? I inspected the browser's network tab (with old and new Firefox) and the `content-type` parameter of that file is `application/xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this configuration and it is working, notice the `set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)` and `self.driver.maximize_window()`that may be not usefull for you.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "src/xls/temp"))
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/vnd.ms-excel')

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
if not DEBUG:
    options.add_argument('--headless')

self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geckodriver'), firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

For future persons I checked that the format the he is using on `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` was corret from the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

Basically, I think that you need to configure the firefox_options as above.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I found this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1670651 and there is mentioned, that you have to clear parameter: `browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes`. Weird thing, this has like 10 english results in google